# Como despliego todos los valores que hay dentro de una lista y al mismo tiempo desplegando cuantos hay de cada uno?? PYTHON

Tags: python

Hola buenas tardes me preguntaba como puedo desplegar todos los valores que hay dentro de una lista y al desplegarlos tambien desplegar cuantos hay de cada valor en la lista en PYTHON. Estoy haciendo un programa de un menu de restaurante y necesito tomar la orden y desplegarle al usuario la orden.

Por ejemplo

Ingrese producto a la orden: Milk Shake

Ingrese producto a la orden: Hamburguesa

Ingrese producto a la orden: Gaseosa

Ingrese producto a la orden: Gaseosa

Ingrese producto a la orden: Papas Fritas

Ingrese producto a la orden: Gaseosa

Su orden es:
1 Milkshake

1 Hamburguesa

3 Gaseosas

1 Papas Fritas

Este es mi codigo

```
menu = {}
menu["The Big Cheese"]=55.00
menu["Texas Burger"]=50.00
menu["Vegan Burger"]=52.00
menu["The Big Boss"]=62.00
menu["Child Burger"]=40.00
menu["Spacy Chicken"]=50.00

menu["Curly Fries"]=14.00
menu["Standard Fries"]=12.00
menu["Onion Rings"]=16.00
menu["Ensalada"]=20.50

menu["Gaseosa en Lata"]=12.00
menu["Gaseosa Refill"]=15.00
menu["Fresco Natural"]=10.00
menu["Milk Shake"]=25.00


#Pedimos ingreso de orden con un ciclo 
orden =[]
def ordenar(producto):

   while True:
       producto = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto que desea agregar a su orden: ")
       print("\n")
       orden.append(producto)
       conteo = orden.count(producto)
       if producto == "Fin":
           print("Su orden: \n")
           print("Su orden ha sido finalizada")
           break
       if producto == "Milk Shake":
           sabor = input("¿De que sabor quiere su Milk Shake?: ")
           print("\n")
           print("Producto agregado a su orden: ",conteo,producto,"sabor",sabor)

       print("Producto agregado a su orden: \n",conteo,producto)`

Ayuda porfavor!! es un proyecto de la uni
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Hola Sebastián, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer mejor el sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. Deberías agregar que has investigado, el código que has intentado y que problema concreto te surge con él a la pregunta. Si puedes usar la stdlib lo que buscas es [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) sin más, si no puedes requiere algo de "inventiva". Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Como opción puedes crear un diccionario en el que vayas acumulando el contenido de la orden. Por ejemplo, en una iteración puedes hacer lo siguiente (primero tendrás que hacer diccionario = {}):

```py
if producto in diccionario:
    diccionario[producto] += 1
else:
    diccionario[producto] = 1
```

Posteriormente podrías iterar el diccionario mediante el siguiente loop:

```py
print("Su orden es: "
for key, value in diccoinario.items():
    print("{} {}".format(value, key)
```

Aunque deberías hacer preguntas menos concretas, dado que lo que pides es prácticamente que resolvamos un ejercicio tuyo en concreto.